# Installing applications onto external sd card?

Tags: chromebook

I recently bought a C720 Chromebook and have since put Ubuntu on it. The only problem I have so far is the limited amount of disk space left on the SSD.

I was wondering if it'd be possible to install apps onto an SD card or USB drive maybe even an external hard drive and run the files from there.

I read into symlinks but I don't really know where to start with those, At the moment I'm trying to install Skype and Steam onto my SD Card without taking up the remaining space on my SSD.

Comment: Welcome to AU! It's possible and not that hard to move around system files and/or user data in Ubuntu. Can you please run `sudo lsblk -o NAME,RM,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT` and [edit] your question to include its output?

Comment: While installing Ubuntu, you can choose to keep the `/usr` folder in a SDCARD partition.

Answer (score 1):

Applications get installed on internal memory which is faster and they are run from there directly. You can save non-applications like songs, videos, and other things on SD card though. If you are very low on internal memory then uninstall some not so frequently used applications.

Answer (score 0):

Move apps from. Ext.sdcard to internal sd to use then backup again when done. Problem is moving appsupport from ext.sdcard.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing. Would you mind to provide more details on how to that?

Answer (score -1):

I am trying vm-ware on an external 64 size card to run another copy of linux onto Ubuntu and load my programs in virtual machine. My trouble is the Acer CB3-111 chromebook has only 2 GB RAM. A fast external drive might help.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1247393)